# Role of name of pandas.Series while doing difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas.Series objects, say `a` and `b`, having the same index, and when performing the difference `a - b` I get the error

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

which I don't understand where is coming from.

The `Series` `a` is obtained as a slice of a DataFrame whose index is a MultiIndex, and when I do a renaming 

`a.name = 0`

the operation works fine (but if I rename to a tuple I get the same error).

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce a minimal example of the phenomenon (the difference of ad-hoc Series with name a tuple seems to work fine).

Any ideas on why this is happening?

If relevant, pandas version is `0.22.0`

### EDIT

The full traceback of the error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-e4efbf202d3c> in <module>()
----> 1 one - two

~/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in wrapper(left, right, name, na_op)
    727 
    728         if isinstance(rvalues, ABCSeries):
--> 729             name = _maybe_match_name(left, rvalues)
    730             lvalues = getattr(lvalues, 'values', lvalues)
    731             rvalues = getattr(rvalues, 'values', rvalues)

~/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in _maybe_match_name(a, b)
    137     b_has = hasattr(b, 'name')
    138     if a_has and b_has:
--> 139         if a.name == b.name:
    140             return a.name
    141         else:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

### EDIT 2

Some more details on how `a` and `b` are obtained:

- I have a DataFrame `df` whose index is a multyindex `(year, id_)`
- I have a Series `factors` whose index are the columns of `df` (something like the standard deviation of the columns)
- Then:

  ```
  tmp = df.loc[(year, id_)]
  a = tmp[factors != 0]
  b = factors[factors != 0]
  diff = a - b
  ```

and executing the last line the error happens.

### EDIT 3

And it keeps happening also if I reduce the columns: the original `df` has around `1000` rows and columns, but reducing to the last 5 lines and columns, the problem persists!

For example, by doing

```
df = df.iloc[-10:][df.columns[-5:]]
line = df.iloc[-3]
factors = factors[df.columns]
a = line[factors != 0]
b = factors[factors != 0]
diff = a - b
```

I keep getting the same error, while printing `a` and `b` I obtain

`a`:

```
end_bin_68.750_100.000    0.002413
end_bin_75.000_100.000    0.002614
end_bin_81.250_100.000    0.001810
end_bin_87.500_100.000    0.002313
end_bin_93.750_100.000    0.001609
Name: (2015, 10000030), dtype: float64
```

`b`:

```
end_bin_68.750_100.000    0.001244
end_bin_75.000_100.000    0.001242
end_bin_81.250_100.000    0.000918
end_bin_87.500_100.000    0.000659
end_bin_93.750_100.000    0.000563
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

While if I manually create `df` and `factors` with these same values (also in the indices) the error does not happen.

### EDIT 4

While debugging, when one gets to the function `_maybe_match_name` one obtains the following:

```
ipdb> type(a.name)
<class 'tuple'>

ipdb> type(b.name)
<class 'numpy.int64'>

ipdb> a.name == b.name
a = end_bin_68.750_100.000    0.002413
end_bin_75.000_100.000    0.002614
end_bin_81.250_100.000    0.001810
end_bin_87.500_100.000    0.002313
end_bin_93.750_100.000    0.001609
Name: (2015, 10000030), dtype: float64
b = end_bin_68.750_100.000    0.001244
end_bin_75.000_100.000    0.001242
end_bin_81.250_100.000    0.000918
end_bin_87.500_100.000    0.000659
end_bin_93.750_100.000    0.000563
Name: 1, dtype: float64

ipdb> (a.name == b.name)
array([False, False])
```

### EDIT 5

Finally I got to a minimal example:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
a.name = np.int64(13)

b = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])
b.name = (123, 789)

a - b
```

this raises the error to me, `np.__version__ == 1.14.0` and `pd.__version__ == 0.22.0`

Comment: hmmm, then it looks like bug :(

Comment: Could you show the full traceback (including the pandas-side lines which are erroring)?  It might help reverse-engineering the problem.

Comment: sounds like you have a duplicate index on 'a' or 'b', maybe test against that?

Comment: @Yuca, I tested that `a.index.equals(b.index)` returns `True`

Comment: @DSM editing the question

Comment: @PietroTortella want I ment is that a itself (or b) has duplicate index, have you tested that?

Comment: @Yuca sorry, I checked now that `len(a.index) == len(a.index.drop_duplicates())`, and the same holds for `b`

Comment: What does `type(a.name)` returns ? It looks like it is an array and I guess the comparison at line 139 is expected to be between two strings.

Could you also gives the output of `a.name` ?

Comment: @AdrienPacifico, `a.name == (2014, 10000052)`, and the type is `type(a.name) == tuple` (also, replacing the name of `a` with smaller numbers gives the same error)

Comment: And can you execute line 139 if you use a debugger ? ( `--pdb` if you execute a script with Ipython, or execute `%debug` if you use a jupyter notebook ). Are a.name and b.name still tuples ?

I tried to reproduce your error with multi-index Series name, I failed to reproduce it...

Comment: @AdrienPacifico I went debug at line 139, and they are both what is expected to be (`type(a) == tuple` and `type(b) == np.int64` )... I have the same problem in reproducing the problem without copying everyhing, I am editing the question with more informations on how `a` and `b` are obtained

Comment: Okay, I think it's time to move this over to github as a bug report.  This is definitely a bug, and I can't reproduce it yet on my side, even with your (excellent, and appreciated!) follow-up.  Path-dependent bugs like these are always frustrating. :-/

Comment: @DSM did you open an issue ?

Comment: @AdrienPacifico: no, I was hoping Pietro could because he's the best situated to continue the debugging conversation.

Comment: thanks, I am going to soon, in the meanwhile maybe I found where the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an operation is made between two pandas `Series` it tries to give a name to the resulting Series.

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s1.name = "hello"
s2.name = "hello"
s3 = s1-s2
s3.name
>>> "hello"
```

If the name is not the same, then the resulting `Series` has no name.

```
s1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s2 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(5))
s1.name = "hello"
s2.name = "goodbye"
s3 = s1-s2
s3.name
>>>
```

This is done by comparing Series names with the function `_maybe_match_name()`, than is [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8fd8d0dc136e0720ce9b2d05f5f8ea8f62833c47/pandas/core/ops.py#L74) on GitHub.

The comparison operator compares apparently in your case an array with a tuple, which is not possible (I haven't been able to reproduce the error), and raise the ValueError exception.

I guess it is a bug, what is weird is that `np.int64(42) == ("A", "B")`doesn't raise an exception for me.
But I have a FutureWarning from numpy:
`FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison.`

Which makes me think that you are using a extremely recent numpy version (you compiled it from the master branch on GitHub ?).

The bug will likely be corrected in next pandas release as it is a result of a future change in the behavior of numpy.

My guess is that the best thing to do is just to rename your Series before making operation as you already did `b.name = None`, or to change your numpy version (`1.15.0`works well).

Comment: on my configuration, `np.int64(42) == ("A", "B")` returns `array(False, False)`, but the numpy version is 1.14.0

Comment: It is really strange that you get an array. I just ran it with numpy 1.14.0 and python 3.6.5 and `np.int64(42) == ("A", "B")` returns `False`. I don't see how this is possible. Are you using python 3.7 ?

Comment: Well I would like to know where does this difference in behaviour come from ? Not from python version apparently. Let us know about the pandas issue :-) .